# Files not getting deleted, if I give clear data in android device

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard, delete-file

In my application I am capturing photos and storing into the SD card.
The location of my file is:

```
      photoPath = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/"
            + "MyFolder" + "/"+"ImageName";
```

But when I give clear data using the "device's clear data option" the file is not getting deleted.When I used the Samsung devices, it is getting deleted. But I am facing this problem when I trying with Lenovo devices.

Any one could you please share your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think that option is meant to clear just the data associated with the app internally.

You have chosen to store extra data on the SD card, and I don't think the system is meant to delete it. You should be managing that yourself.

Which brings up the question of why Samsung is able to delete that file? I do not know why.

Answer (score -1):

May be it depends upon the device.

If you want to delete the entire content in a folder, try this code.

```
void DeleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {

     if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
          for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
               DeleteRecursive(child);

              fileOrDirectory.delete();
}
```

Comment: Yeah I understood. But I wonder how it is happening in Samsung devices?